# Twitter via Cocoa App using MGTwitterEngine: HTTP error 401

Tags: macos, cocoa, twitter, mgtwitterengine, http-error

I use `MGTwitterEngine` library in my Cocoa application to allow sending tweets.

Here's my code:

```
    NSString *username = MyName;
    NSString *password = MyPass;

    NSString *consumerKey = ConsumerKey;;
    NSString *consumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;

    // Most API calls require a name and password to be set...
    if (! username || ! password || !consumerKey || !consumerSecret) {
        NSLog(@"You forgot to specify your username/password/key/secret in AppController.m, things might not work!");
        NSLog(@"And if things are mysteriously working without the username/password, it's because NSURLConnection is using a session cookie from another connection.");
    }

    // Create a TwitterEngine and set our login details.
    twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [twitterEngine setUsesSecureConnection:NO];
    [twitterEngine setConsumerKey:consumerKey secret:consumerSecret];

    [twitterEngine setUsername:username password:password];

    OAToken *token = [[OAToken alloc] initWithKey:tokenKey
                                  secret:tokenSecret];
    [twitterEngine setAccessToken:token];
    [twitterEngine sendUpdate:@"twitter post"];
```

It builds without any errors. When I run my app this occurs in output:

*[Switching to process 1853 thread 0x0]
Catchpoint 3 (throw)* **2012-02-17 17:07:57.790 Dreamer[1853:1203] MGTwitterEngine: finalURL = http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml**

**2012-02-17 17:07:57.791 Dreamer[1853:1203] MGTwitterEngine: finalBody = status=twitter%20post**

*[Switching to process 1853 thread 0x620b]* 
**2012-02-17 18:30:38.491 Dreamer[2067:1203] Request failed for connectionIdentifier = DAAC2B20-91B6-49A6-90CA-4FD0606DA2FB, error = The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.) ({
    body = "\n\n  Read-only application cannot POST\n  /1/statuses/update.xml\n\n";
    response = "";
})**

And no tweets appear in Twitter.

I registered the application on dev.twitter.com and put access as `Read, Write and Access direct messages`

Where the problem may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved.

If someone will face the same problem then regenerate your access token key after access changing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613727/iphone-why-i-got-this-error-http-error-401-twitter